# How to solve error: cannot find symbol class DatabaseReference problem

Tags: android

I'm working on the android application and when I want to connect with firebase. I have an:

> error: cannot find symbol class DatabaseReference

Error. My code:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getreference();
    }
}
```

My build.gradle(Project:android)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
```

My build.gradle(Module: app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ala.marouene"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services
```

And I already have JSON file in my .app folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Realtime Database:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0"
```

But you'd generally need to use elder versions of Firebase, which still were built against `com.android.support` libraries - or migrate the whole project to `androidx` libraries.